# Handlebars, mongoDB & JS: Cannot get the ID

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, express-handlebars

Trying to do a web tutorial, I am using mongoDB, handlebars and nodeJS for the application. I have one part of the code reserved for deleting users but it seems that is not getting the ID of the users when I do the delete. Hereunder the code in handlebars:

```
<div class = "row">
    {{#each notes}}
        <div class = "col-md-3">
            <div class = "card">
                <div class= "card-body">
                    <h4 class = "card-title d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                        {{title}} <a href="/notes/edit/{{_id}}"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>
                    </h4>
                    <p>{{description}}</p>
                    <form action="/notes/delete/{{_id}}?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
                        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-block btn-sm">Delete</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {{else}}
        <div class = "card mx-auto">
            <div class= "card-body">
                <p class="lead">Inserte una nueva tarea</p>
                <a href="/notes/add" class="bt btn-success btn-block"> Crea una!</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

The code for deleting is just after description, between the line 9 and 13 of the code. And hereunder, the code in JS for deleting:

```
router.delete("/notes/delete/:id", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.params.id);
    res.send("OK");
});
```

When I update and run the app what I obtained is: `Cannot DELETE /notes/delete/`So, I understand that handlebars is not getting the _id of the data, so that, is not appearing anything in my console, thus, I understand that JS is not doing anything.

Thank you

Comment: Please also add the route from where you are serving this handlebars page

Comment: Please post the route that renders that `view`, thank you!